# Java: Trouble with uploading files

Tags: java, file-upload, seam

Using Java (Seam + JBoss) and having a lot of difficulty trying to update a file.

I'm using the Seam fileUpload tag and have the form encoding type set as "multipart/form-data". When I select a file and submit the form, however, I'm getting an exception.

The form code is as follows:

```
<h:form id="registration" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h:outputText value="#{messages['profile.title']}"/>
    <fieldset>
    
     <!-- s:decorate id="usernameDecorate" template="edit.xhtml" -->
      <ui:define name="label">Name:</ui:define>
      <h:inputText id="name" value="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.name}" required="true">
       <!-- a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="usernameDecorate"/ -->
      </h:inputText>
     <!-- /s:decorate -->
     
     <!-- s:decorate id="usernameDecorate" template="edit.xhtml" -->
      <ui:define name="label">Email:</ui:define>
      <h:inputText id="email" value="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.email}" required="true">
       <!--  a:support id="onblur" event="onblur" reRender="usernameDecorate"/-->
      </h:inputText>
     <!-- /s:decorate -->
     
     <ui:define name="label">#{messages['profile.fieldlabel.photo']}</ui:define>
     
     <s:fileUpload id="file" name="file"
      data="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.data}"
      contentType="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.contentType}"
      fileName="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.filename}"
      fileSize="#{editProfileAction.editProfileFormData.size}" />
     
     
     <div class="buttonBox">
      <h:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save" action="#{editProfileAction.update}"/>
      &#160;
      <s:button id="cancel" value="Cancel" view="/home.xhtml"/>
     </div>
```

The exception I'm getting is as follows:

```
Exception during request processing:
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException with message: ""

org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartRequestImpl.parseRequest(MultipartRequestImpl.java:391)
org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartRequestImpl.getParameterNames(MultipartRequestImpl.java:530)
org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:84)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
```

Comment: Can you post longer stack trace or classes which represents editProfileAction? There is not enough information to relate your html to your exception stack trace.

Comment: Do as gigadot says. Give us longer stacktrace and post your beans. Much easier then.

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException`

You should learn about pointers.

Somewhere you didn't say `Foo foo = new Foo()`. I bet about 3 more lines down the stack trace will tell us where. Unless you called `org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartRequestImpl.parseRequest` yourself.

Comment: I most definitely know pointers. I'm working with a number of frameworks that, to my knowledge, should be handling all this stuff. I defined an upload form which should (assuming my understanding is correct - I'm a bit swamped with all this technology at the moment but there's little I can do but push through), after the form is submitted, populate a model object and then call the update method, at which point I can start playing around with the form data. Only, when I specify the encoding type as multipart/form-data, the app doesn't make it that far.

Comment: Tomorrow when I get to work, i`ll try to help you. Never tried this, but there`s a project running on Seam. Let`s see if I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

We used richfaces to upload here:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="fileUpload"
   progressLabel="Uploading"
   maxFilesQuantity="10"
   listHeight="90px"
   listWidth="400px"
   addControlLabel="Select"
   noDuplicate="true"
   fileUploadListener="#{someJavaHome.uploadFile}"
   clearAllControlLabel="Clear"
   uploadControlLabel="Add Files"
   doneLabel="Done"
   cancelEntryControlLabel="Cancel"
   clearControlLabel="Clear"
   transferErrorLabel="Oops! Upload didn't work out."
   sizeErrorLabel="Cannot be bigger than 1MB"> 
</rich:fileUpload>


public void uploadFile(UploadEvent uploadEvent) throws IOException{
   try {
      if(uploadEvent == null){
         return;
      }

      for (UploadItem uploadItem : uploadEvent.getUploadItems()) {
         if(!this.uploadItems.contains(uploadItem)){
            this.uploadItems.add(uploadItem);
         }
      }

   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```